# unbadging app icon (swift) execution problems

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, badge

Hey Guys so what I am trying to do is when the user gets a notification then goes into the app or clears it in the notification settings I want to debadge the app icon

```
import UIKit

class TechByteSchedulingViewController:UIViewController  {

    @IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!

    @IBAction func DateChosen(sender: UIButton) {
        self.sendNotification()
    }

    func sendNotification() {

        var localNotification = UILocalNotification()
        localNotification.fireDate = datePicker.date
        localNotification.repeatInterval = .CalendarUnitDay
        localNotification.alertBody = "check out your Daily Tech Byte"
        localNotification.alertAction = "Open"
        localNotification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
        localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1
        localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)

}
    func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelAllLocalNotifications()

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought it was

```
application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
```

or

```
currentInstalltion.badge = 0
```

and then saving it in the background

No?

Comment: For both make sure it's in AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function and you saveInBackground.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try

```
application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
```

in your AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function